# Can an Android Service have multiple Permissions?

Tags: java, android, permissions, manifest

I have a service which both downloads a file and saves it, and it seems I can only specify one permission.

```
<service android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".DownloadService" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">            
</service>
```

or

```
<service android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".DownloadService" android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">            
</service>
```

I need both.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An Android `Service` can have multiple permissions, but permissions are granted at the application level, not at the `Service` level.

Your problem is that you are trying to grant permission to your `Service` in the wrong place in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

The [`android:permission` attribute of a `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#prmsn) specifies the permission that an entity must have to use the service, not a permission granted to the  `Service`.

You [grant permissions to all components your application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions) at the top level of your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.yourdomain.yourapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: how a serice can have more than one permission?

Comment: What if you need to specify that an entity have more than one permission to use the service?