# How to require multiple permissions to launch or bind to a Service

Tags: android, permissions

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html), the Android manifest file can have the following syntax for a `Service`:

```
<service android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
         android:exported=["true" | "false"]
         android:icon="drawable resource"
         android:isolatedProcess=["true" | "false"]
         android:label="string resource"
         android:name="string"
         android:permission="string"
         android:process="string" >
    . . .
</service>
```

The permission attribute in particular specifies:

> The name of a permission that that an entity must have in order to
>   launch the service or bind to it.

But it seems I cannot request more than one permission for an entity to launch my service. Is that really the case? Is there anyway to circumvent this?

Here on Stackoverflow the closest I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3474111) where the author says that:

> An Android Service can have multiple permissions, but permissions are
>   granted at the application level, not at the Service level.

But then he goes on to explain the `<uses-permission>` attribute which is not what I'm looking for. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421084) reduces my hopes even further. It seems this is indeed not possible.

If that is the case, the alternative I'm considering is to have one service for each permission I require and make them all work as forwarders to the actual service in charge of doing the job. Any better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that really the case?

In terms of automatic protection in the manifest, yes. That's the 99.9% case.

> Is there anyway to circumvent this?

Check for the other permission in Java code, using something [like `checkCallingPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingPermission%28java.lang.String%29).

> But then he goes on to explain the  attribute which is not what I'm looking for.

Correct.

> the alternative I'm considering is to have one service for each permission I require and make them all work as forwarders to the actual service in charge of doing the job.

That would only make sense if you are trying to have a logical OR on the permissions, where the caller has to have permission X *or* permission Y. Up until this point in your question, I had assumed that you wanted a logical AND on the permissions (caller must hold permission X *and* permission Y).

I cannot think of a scenario where a logical OR for incoming permissions would be useful, let alone necessary. That being said, your workaround should work if you are using the command pattern with `startService()`, having the "real" service be not exported, and where you call `stopSelf()` after forwarding the command on from your exported services. If your vision was to use this proxy approach with the binding pattern, using `bindService()`, may `$DEITY` have mercy on your soul, 'cause you're gonna need it.